# Is there anyway to do multiple repeated translations with the google translate API

Tags: javascript, html, translation, google-translate, google-api-js-client

As of now I have a script element to which I attach my api request to by doing whenever an onclick is registered and sourceText is the text needing to be translated. The call back function just prints something out on the webpage (Changes a global variable, then a separate function outputs that global variable)

```
  source = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=YOUR_API_KEY&source=en&target=de&callback=translateText&q=' + sourceText;
  newScript.src = source;
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newScript);
```

The problem is it works for the first translation (first onclick) but after that the translations don't change after adding the script to the head. In fact the callback function is never called after the first call and the new output is just the first translated string. Any way to fix this?

As I understand there's probably an easier way to do this with google.load("language") could someone point me in the right direction then?

Answer (score 0):

As of now you are using a kind of a hackyish way of calling the script. While the script is some kind of 'executing', I would recommend to write a kind of class and fire real ajax requests. To make it a bit easier for yourself, I would use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (or something like that), and write a maintanable class. It could look something like this (not tested in any way, but gives you a clue ;))

```
var Translate = function( translateHandler ) {
    this.endpoint = 'https://www.googleapis/language/translate/v2';
    this.apiKey = 'xyz';
    this.translateHandler = translateHandler;
};

Translate.prototype.translate = function ( text, source, target ) {
    $.get(this.endpoint, {
        key: this.apiKey,
        q: text,
        source: source,
        target: target
    }, this.translateHandler.bind(this));
};

// usage
var handler = function( result) {
    // do something with the result
};
var translater = new Translate( handler );

$('#myButton').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    translater.translate( $('#source').text(), 'en', 'de') );
})
```

Comment: Ahh I was looking for the $.get function. Thanks! Just had to add that instead of adding appendChild over and over again. The documentation for it wasn't very clear.